# User Activity logs on Airflow or Composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

Is there any way I can access user-activity logs in Airflow? I would like to see some actions performed by users in Airflow.

Comment: According to the documentation, [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs), you can see the logs. When you create an environment Cloud Composer creates a Cloud Storage bucket , this bucket stores the logs for single DAGS tasks in **logs**. Also, in the provided link there are instructions how to do so. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to user activity in the Airflow UI, tracking this is not something supported by Cloud Composer at this time. This partially because RBAC is not currently supported for Airflow on Composer, so activity would be logged on a per-IAM user basis as opposed to a per-Airflow user basis.

That being said, the managed Composer webserver doesn't currently log data access, so if this is something you need, I would recommend [filing a feature request](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests).